# Multiple tests of a single record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Excuse the cross posting but I've asked this elsewhere without a reply, so I'll try StackOverflow:

I'm interested in testing a string field in each record for several things:

- the number of times that something occurs in the string,
- the number of times that several different things occur in the string
  together at the same time, etc., including the record in the selection if a variety of criteria are achieved, otherwise not.

For example, if the letter "a" occurs at least 3 times, or maybe if "a" and "b" don't occur together more than 2 times in that field, or if at least any 2 of the letters "a" or "b" or "c" can be found then the record would be output (i.e. included in the set/collection of all records that meet that criteria).

It would seem that I would have to test the field of each record multiple times to accomplish those.

I could use either the "meta_where" gem or regular SQL, but I can't think of how to do this with either.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
         Barney